# vba application.workbooks.open() Error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()
   Name = "C:\Users\zif\Desktop\CAT\as1_new\tt.xlsx"
   wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zif\Desktop\CAT\as1_new\tt.xlsx")
End Sub
```

this is my code and i just want to test it.
I am sure the directory and filename is correct, and the file is not opened, but i still have this error

---

update: 
Thank you for answering my questions
I have changed my code to below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    myName = "C:\Users\zif\Desktop\CAT\as1_new\tt.xlsx"
    Set wb=Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zif\Desktop\CAT\as1_new\tt.xlsx")
End Sub
```

but it still throws the same error message to me.

Comment: You need to declare and set your variables, Name & 'wb', especially 'wb'.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you not to use variables declared as `Name` because it's a reserved word for VBA. It's way better to use something like `MyName`, `ThisName`, `vName` and stuff like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to initialize `wb` first, like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
```

When assigning th object you need to use the `Set`statement, like this:

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\zif\Desktop\CAT\as1_new\tt.xlsx")
```

Edit: There is a lot of good additional advice in the comments to the question, which should be considered.

Comment: Hi, i have changed my codes to initialize the wb by adding in ```Dim wb As Workbook``` however it still throws me the same error.

Comment: @zifanyan did you also incorporate the `Set` statement from my second line?